# Breadboard header for usbasp

Tags: connector, breadboard, pins, header

I am not able to find any breadboard headers for this particular usb asp connector

[Here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/USBISP-USBasp-USB-ISP-USB-ASP-Programmer-Downloader-for-ATMEL-AVR-Adapter-/291167433873?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43caee7491)

They do exist because I've seen then at school, but I can't seem to find them online. I bought breakable male male pins, but they are too short to fit in the board. I also bought a black header for it on ebay, but it is also too short for the breadboard, only good for soldering.

Comment: So solder it :P  I find 0.6mm solid core wire is good for jumpering between IDC connectors and breadboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 different solutions that I've used for this:

1. Loose wires inserted into the IDC and breadboard

   This works for any chip, but can be a pain to move between chips.
2. PCB-mounted adapter using extra-long headers

   This must be done custom per chip but is extremely reliable, and allows additional embellishments such as a button to make powering the chip from the programmer optional.

I will include pictures of both solutions when I am able to.

Comment: Yeah, but my school has the headers. Why can't I find them online then?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1465)?

Comment: No, I mean something like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10-Pcs-2-54mm-2x5-Pin-10-Pin-Straight-Male-Shrouded-PCB-Box-header-IDC-Socket-/171047381713?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27d337ead1) but with the lower pins long enough that can coneect to the breadboard because these ones are too small

Comment: Sounds like a wire-wrap IDC header connector. Fairly hard to find these days.

Comment: Yes, from googling this it looks like what I am looking for, thanks, I guess I'll have to stick with inserting wires in the IDC.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do. Get some of these 11.5 mm male DIL headers (eBay):
[image]
Trim it down to:
[image]
Move the black plastic pin spacer to about half way if necessary, and insert:
[image]
...works a treat :)

You can get longer ones - just search eBay for "male pin header long double row".

Answer (score 0):

So long story short, I was looking for electronics surplus stores in the area, and look what I found:

[image: Stupid sexy Flanders!]

Found at [Creatron Inc](https://www.creatroninc.com/). It doesn't show on their [product page](https://www.creatroninc.com/category/breadboard-prototyping/breadboard-adapter/idc-ribbon-breadboard-adapters), but I'm sure you can drop them a line and they'll help you.